# Compare average roc auc scores using T-Test

Tags: machine-learning, t-test, roc

I am using xgbclassifier to do feature selection by removing variables based on feature importance. I checked the roc_auc_score through 10 cv, and got an average value of 0.785 when 5 features were removed and 0.786 when 12 features were removed. However, the simple average is not clear whether the model with 12 variables removed is better than the model with 5 variables removed. I found it difficult to judge.

So, I'm trying to use T-Test as a solution to this, but I'm wondering if it's an appropriate method.

Comment: Whether the T-test yields a low p-value or not, substantively there can hardly be a difference when the mean AUCs are so similar.  How many candidate predictors do you have all in all?

Comment: Testing is not usually done on ROC-AUC scores.

Comment: The number of features is 49, and one-hot encoding is performed to remove 159 independent variables one by one.